# kafka HDFS connector connecting to private IP instead of hostname in multi-DC setup

Tags: hadoop, hortonworks-data-platform, confluent-platform, apache-kafka-connect

I have 2 clusters:

- one in house with confluent (3.0.0-1)
- one in AWS, with hadoop (hdp 2.4)

I am trying to use the hdfs connector to write from confluent to hadoop.

Long story short: the connector tries to connect to a private IP of the hadoop cluster instead of using the hostname. On the in-house cluster, /etc/hosts has been updated to resolve the internal hadoop hostnames to the relevant public IP.

I am using the distributed connector, I have a bunch of connector JSON files as follow:

```
{
   "name": "sent-connector",

   "connector.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.HdfsSinkConnector",
   "tasks.max": "1",
   "topics": "sent",

   "topics.dir":"/kafka-connect/topics",
   "logs.dir":"/kafka-connect/wal",
   "hdfs.url": "hdfs://ambari:8020",

   "hadoop.conf.dir": "/etc/hadoop/conf",
   "hadoop.home": "/usr/hdp/current/hadoop-client",

   "flush.size": "100",

   "hive.integration":"true",
   "hive.metastore.uris":"thrift://ambari:9083",
   "hive.database":"events",
   "hive.home": "/usr/hdp/current/hive-client",
   "hive.conf.dir": "/etc/hive/conf",

   "schema.compatibility":"FULL",

   "partitioner.class": "io.confluent.connect.hdfs.partitioner.HourlyPartitioner",
   "path.format": "'year'=YYYY/'month'=MM/'day'=dd/'hour'=HH/",
   "locale": "C",
   "timezone": "UTC",

   "rotate.interval.ms": "2000"

}
```

and the worker is defined as such:

```
rest.port=8083
bootstrap.servers=<eth0 IP of the server>:9092
group.id=dp2hdfs
key.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
key.converter.schema.registry.url=schemareg.dpe.webpower.io
value.converter=io.confluent.connect.avro.AvroConverter
value.converter.schema.registry.url=schemareg.dpe.webpower.io
internal.key.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.value.converter=org.apache.kafka.connect.json.JsonConverter
internal.key.converter.schemas.enable=false
internal.value.converter.schemas.enable=false
config.storage.topic=k2hdfs-configs
offset.storage.topic=k2hdfs-offsets
status.storage.topic=k2hdfs-statuses
debug=true
```

A few notes:

- /kafka-connect exists on hdfs, world-writeable
- The 3 topics (*.storage.topic) do exist
- I have one worker running on each (3) servers with kafka broker (there is a schema registry, rest API and zookeeper server as well on all brokers)
- I have set dfs.client.use.datanode.hostname  to true, and this property is set up on the client in $HADOOP_HOME/hdfs-site.xml

I see that the subdirectories of /kafka-connect are created as well as hive metadata. When I start the connector, the message is:

> INFO Exception in createBlockOutputStream (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient:1471)
>   org.apache.hadoop.net.ConnectTimeoutException: 60000 millis timeout while waiting for channel to be ready for connect. ch : java.nio.channels.SocketChannel[connection-pending remot
>   at org.apache.hadoop.net.NetUtils.connect(NetUtils.java:533)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream.createSocketForPipeline(DFSOutputStream.java:1610)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.createBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1408)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.nextBlockOutputStream(DFSOutputStream.java:1361)
>   at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSOutputStream$DataStreamer.run(DFSOutputStream.java:588)
>   INFO Abandoning BP-429601535-10.0.0.167-1471011443948:blk_1073742319_1495 (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient:1364)
>   INFO Excluding datanode 10.0.0.231:50010 (org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.DFSClient:1368)
>   [rince and repeat with other datanodes]

Any idea on how to fix this? It looks like confluent receives the IP directly, not a hostname.

Comment: Short story short: HDFS client contacts NameNode (using its public address) and requests creation of a new file; NN replies with the host:port of the DataNode that has been assigned as primary writer, **as known by the NameNode**; boom.

Comment: If you have access to your router configuration, you could try NATting (or rather PATting) all possible IP:ports for AWS DataNodes to their public equivalents, so that your client follows the (goofy) NN instructions but traffic is tunnelled automatically to the (correct) destination. Yuck.

Comment: My issue is that NN should use hostname:port, not IP:port. That should work as in /etc/hosts of the kafka cluster I bound those hostnames to the public IP of the DNs.

Comment: The NN configuration mentions **DNS** settings. Not sure it cares about `/etc/hosts` because it would not work with Kerberos anyway (Krb requires *canonical* DNS names by default, to avoid IP spoofing attacks)